# How to do an "exit animation" manually using AOS?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, animation, repository

In an excerpt from the @michalsnik repository, he explains how to make custom animations in the case of a responsive website. However, when making an animation like the one shown, it does not leave the screen as it scrolls, with the data-aos-mirror function being marked as true or false. I would like to know how to manually do the exit animations or if there is a better way to do it. Thanks.

OBS: My project is a React model and it will be better if the animation could be made in css, and not in JavaScript.

**An excerpt from the animation I made:**

```
[data-aos="AnimaT"] {
        @media(max-width: 1180px){
            opacity: 0;
            filter: blur(5px);
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: all;

            &.aos-animate {
                opacity: 1;
                filter: blur(0);
                transform: translateX(0);
                transition-duration: 2000ms;
            }
        }
        @media(max-width: 840px){
            transition-duration: 500ms;
        }
}
```